# Error while trying to graph a decision boundary for a KNN

Tags: python, numpy, machine-learning, scikit-learn, knn

I have a csv dataframe with 2 variables (an input dataframe, denoted by X) and another numpy array consisting of my target variables.

This looks something like this:

```
>X

    Duration  Grand Mean
0        142  383.076805
1        334  182.067833
2         97  232.677513
3        220  448.385085
4        127  251.524975
5        121  156.828771
```

```
>y
[13 11 11 13 12 11 11 13 12 11 12 13 11 12 12 13 13 12 13 12 11 13 13 12
 12 13 13 13 12 13 13 11 13 13 11 13 11 12 13 13 13 11 11 12 13 13 12 12
 12 11]
```

I have not included the dataframe for this particular exercise because the error that I get is quite universal for any csv file that I use, so I assume that the problem is inherently tied to the method that I used.

So, I tried:

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from matplotlib.colors import ListedColormap
from sklearn import neighbors, datasets

n_neighbors = 15




h = .02  # step size in the mesh

# Create color maps
cmap_light = ListedColormap(['orange', 'cyan', 'cornflowerblue'])
cmap_bold = ListedColormap(['darkorange', 'c', 'darkblue'])

for weights in ['uniform', 'distance']:
    # we create an instance of Neighbours Classifier and fit the data.
    clf = neighbors.KNeighborsClassifier(n_neighbors, weights=weights)
    clf.fit(X, y)

    # Plot the decision boundary. For that, we will assign a color to each
    # point in the mesh [x_min, x_max]x[y_min, y_max].
    x_min, x_max = X[:, 0].min() - 1, X[:, 0].max() + 1
    y_min, y_max = X[:, 1].min() - 1, X[:, 1].max() + 1
    xx, yy = np.meshgrid(np.arange(x_min, x_max, h),
                         np.arange(y_min, y_max, h))
    Z = clf.predict(np.c_[xx.ravel(), yy.ravel()])

    # Put the result into a color plot
    Z = Z.reshape(xx.shape)
    plt.figure()
    plt.pcolormesh(xx, yy, Z, cmap=cmap_light)

    # Plot also the training points
    plt.scatter(X[:, 0], X[:, 1], c=y, cmap=cmap_bold,
                edgecolor='k', s=20)
    plt.xlim(xx.min(), xx.max())
    plt.ylim(yy.min(), yy.max())
    plt.title("3-Class classification (k = %i, weights = '%s')"
              % (n_neighbors, weights))

plt.show()
```

With the following error message:

```
TypeError: '(slice(None, None, None), 0)' is an invalid key
```

I have seen a similar post on this topic but I could not get the answer for that question to work for me.

Comment: IIUC, you can't do `X[:, 0]` if `X` is a dataframe. you could do `iloc`: X.iloc[:,0]`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your error is due to the way you slice pandas `df` (you do it like it were a numpy array which is obviously wrong).

One possible way of correcting it, put the line:

```
X = X.values
```

at the top of your code and you're fine to go.

**Proof**

```
X = pd.DataFrame(np.random.randn(100,2), columns=["Duration","Grand Mean"])
X = X.values # <--- put this line
y = np.random.choice([11,12,13],100,True,[.33,.33,.34])

import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from matplotlib.colors import ListedColormap
from sklearn import neighbors, datasets

n_neighbors = 15

h = .02  # step size in the mesh

# Create color maps
cmap_light = ListedColormap(['orange', 'cyan', 'cornflowerblue'])
cmap_bold = ListedColormap(['darkorange', 'c', 'darkblue'])

for weights in ['uniform', 'distance']:
    # we create an instance of Neighbours Classifier and fit the data.
    clf = neighbors.KNeighborsClassifier(n_neighbors, weights=weights)
    clf.fit(X, y)

    # Plot the decision boundary. For that, we will assign a color to each
    # point in the mesh [x_min, x_max]x[y_min, y_max].
    x_min, x_max = X[:, 0].min() - 1, X[:, 0].max() + 1
    y_min, y_max = X[:, 1].min() - 1, X[:, 1].max() + 1
    xx, yy = np.meshgrid(np.arange(x_min, x_max, h),
                         np.arange(y_min, y_max, h))
    Z = clf.predict(np.c_[xx.ravel(), yy.ravel()])

    # Put the result into a color plot
    Z = Z.reshape(xx.shape)
    plt.figure()
    plt.pcolormesh(xx, yy, Z, cmap=cmap_light)

    # Plot also the training points
    plt.scatter(X[:, 0], X[:, 1], c=y, cmap=cmap_bold,
                edgecolor='k', s=20)
    plt.xlim(xx.min(), xx.max())
    plt.ylim(yy.min(), yy.max())
    plt.title("3-Class classification (k = %i, weights = '%s')"
              % (n_neighbors, weights))

plt.show()
```

[image]